# Insert into database with jQuery POST

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have problem to insert into database using jQuery POST

in js

```
var us = result.user;
alert(us.email); //someone@gmail.com
var user = JSON.stringify(result.user);
$.post("signup.php", user);
```

in php,

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['user'], true);
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dbname");
$conn->query("INSERT INTO users (uid, name, email, number) VALUES (\'".$data['uid']."\', \'".$data['displayName']."\', \'".$data['email']."\', \'".$data['phoneNumber']."\')");
```

It's not inserting into db, above one not working.

please give me code to insert into db with jQuery $.POST

Comment: You should consider adding your error into the question.

Comment: any error message?
Just a note, your code is prone to SQL injection, you should take care of that.

Comment: take the query in to variable and dump it.

Comment: please give me code to insert into db with jQuery $.POST

Comment: "_please give me code to insert into db with jQuery $.POST_" That's not how SO works I'm afraid.

Comment: how to access json data in php,

Comment: @Sameera already gave you a hint. You could also just `var_dump($data)` to see which fields it contains. Hint: no need to escape single quotes `\'` in double quotes. Turn on error reporting. Use [mysqli_error](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: where is the posted data for uid, name and phone??

Answer (score 0):

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* rather then JSON.stringify i had used the simple varibale  */
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.post("demo_test_post.php",{name: "Donald Duck",city: "Duckburg"},
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
```

PHP code for AJAX request:

```
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
$name = $_POST['name'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
/* you can now pass this variables in the query and insert your data easily */
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                $("#unit").val('');
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: $("#hdnService").val() + "InsertUomData",
                        data: "{'Uom':'" + $("#unit").val() + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {

});
//you have to pass parameter in data: section. same parameter fetch in service class. you have to define the same name of the parameter in service.cs and aspx file
```